# Need example of how to override jQuery validator "delegate" method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to know how I can override a jquery.validate.js function.  I want to leave the plug-in "pure" and override one function that's causing an issue in my application.

Version 1.9.0 of the plugin has the following function on line #311.

```
function delegate(event) {
var validator = $.data(this[0].form, "validator"),
     eventType = "on" + event.type.replace(/^validate/, "");
validator.settings[eventType] && validator.settings[eventType].call(validator, this[0], event);
}
```

Here's the desired implementation (without changing the original source).

```
function delegate(event) {
    if (this[0].form != null) {
var validator = $.data(this[0].form, "validator"),
     eventType = "on" + event.type.replace(/^validate/, "");
validator.settings[eventType] && validator.settings[eventType].call(validator,    this[0], event);
 }
```

I tried something like this (created a plug-in) but don't have much experience at creating overridden functions.

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.prototype.init.delegate = function (event) {
    if (this[0].form != null) {
        var validator = $.data(this[0].form, "validator"),
            eventType = "on" + event.type.replace(/^validate/, "");
        validator.settings[eventType] && validator.settings[eventType].call(validator, this[0], event);
    }   
}
}(jQuery));

}
```

Comment: I suspect the real problem is in *your* code. Probably be better to address the issue in your application than to try and rewrite someone else's years-old tried-and-tested plugin.

Comment: Your "desired" version of the function is missing a closing brace, `}`... and exactly what @Blazemonger just said.  In the 4000 questions tagged with [tag:jquery-validate], nobody has ever asked about how to over-ride the `delegate` function inside the plugin.  Have you tried version 1.11.1 yet?

Comment: There is no way of replacing the delegate function without also replacing the init function. Suggest instead modifying the plugin directly if you want to change that method. (either by making said function available to be extended, or by just changing it)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I'm trying to get undocumented code working where there are forms within forms, etc. with hierarchical grids of Infragistics IgniteUI (pretty complicated)  When I click within one form, then outside of it there is no form active so when it's trying to get to occurrence [0] of the form it's null.  So I wanted to insert an if not null.  When I do it works perfectly and al other validation does too.  But I do appreciate the suggestions.